# How to change width of the image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want my image to be w-100 when screen is lg or bigger and w-50 when screen is md and smaller

```
<div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 order-md-2"><img src='image.png' class="w-100 w-md-50"> 
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Is there a boostrap class where I can write at which size which width would be? In my code I tried to write `w-md-5` in accordance with `offset-md-1`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think Bootstrap 4 provides width utilities by breakpoint, just as a general setting [(w-25, w-50, etc.)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/sizing/).

You could add your own width style:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .w-md-50 {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

I didn't test it but you may try to do it reversely - `<img src='image.png' class="w-50 w-md-100">`

as w-50 will mean from extra small to the medium and w-md-100 will mean from medium or 768px to above ..